# Form validation failing in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, validation, python-3.x

Im trying to get a form to validate with a Charfield but using the Select widget.

Here is my `view.py` code:

```
def mpld3plot(request):
    form = PlotlyPlotForm()
    form.fields['plot_file'].widget.choices = own_funcs.uploaded_files(string=False)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(form.is_valid())
        if form.is_valid():

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/mpld3')

        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass

    return render(request, 'evert/plot.html', {'plottype': 'MPLD3',
                                               'form': form})
```

Below is my `forms.py` code:

```
class Mpld3PlotForm(forms.Form):

    plot_file = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=[('', 'a'), ('', 'b')]))
```

The form does not validate on submit. I update the choices dynamically based on uploaded files. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I did not pass the `request` object to the form.

The `view.py` file should look like the following:

```
def mpld3plot(request):
    form = PlotlyPlotForm(request.POST)
    form.fields['plot_file'].widget.choices = own_funcs.uploaded_files(string=False)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(form.is_valid())
        if form.is_valid():

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/mpld3')

        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass

    return render(request, 'evert/plot.html', {'plottype': 'MPLD3',
                                               'form': form})
```